# NSPredicate Exact Match with String

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

hello I am working on swift. I need to know how can I find results which matches the exact string. Here's my code

```
let userID: String = String(sender.tag)
        // Create a Predicate with mapping to trip_id
        let filterByRequest: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@", "ProductRequest", "user_id", userID)
        // Filter your main array with predicate, resulting array will have filtered objects
        let filteredArray: [AnyObject] = self.array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(filterByRequest)
```

The problem is If user id is 69 it shows results of users whose id is 69, 6, and 9.

I googled but I find some answers closed to my question but they were all in objective C.

Comment: because you are using CONTAINS[c] .. means if any character is in that field you got that

Comment: yes what should I use then ?@EICaptain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **MATCHES** in predicate as following :

```
let filterByRequest: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K MATCHES %@", "ProductRequest", "user_id", userID)
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: "MATCHES" does a *regular expression* matching. This will not work if the search string contains any regex special characters.

Answer (score 1):

To test for exact equality, simply use `==` instead of `CONTAINS`:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K == %@", ...)
```

This can also be combined with `[c]` for case-insensitive equality:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K ==[c] %@", ...)
```